# Wine only partly clearred

Tags: wine, racking

I have a white wine that finished fermenting over 2 weeks ago, I racked into a 2nd demi through a muslin filter to be sure i dont have any larger bits floating around.

I added some clearing gel, and the wine did get less "thick" than it was, but was still not close to being clear, so 3 days ago, i racked a 2nd time into another demi.

Now, i have the wine in a 3rd demi, no sediment at all, but, the top 1cm or so of the 1gal demi is completely clear, but below that, haze/slightly opaque.

Is this a sign that it is clearing and i should just let gravity take its course, or have i messed something up here?

Answer (score 1):

The top layer being clear is indeed and indicator that the rest will likely drop as sediment. However because it is so fine and probably still in suspension in part due to Brownian motion, you need to be sure the Demi-John is undisturbed. Put it on a surface that doesn't shake as you walk past. Don't keep checking it all the time. Just let it be.

In the end you may finally give up and use a dining agent and or filter, but it real behooves you to try to be patient and let it clear on its own if you can.

Answer (score -1):

Relax Don't Worry Have Homebrew.
I'm sure time and gravity will clear it up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3973)

Comment: And how does it NOT answer the question? His only question was if he messed something up, imo he did not and it just needs more time to clear.

Comment: It isn't a direct answer. Take a look at my answer and yours. In the very general sense we both said the same thing, but I provided more details. I don't even think my answer is the best there can be. Some people link pictures and quote other resources in their answers. That honestly seems to be the preferred flavor of answer here.

Comment: Well I don't believe every answer needs to be convoluted with science with references. When the solution is quite literally.... Do nothing and wait. I guess I could have explained the principles of gravity and added if he has access to a large centrifuge or g-force simulator he could expedite the process.

Comment: I know, sometimes it's frustrating when to you and I the simplest answer is clearest. But do you dispute the value of the added information about minimizing disturbance? That's what this site is about not just giving the correct answer but the best one.